# PyYAML custom tag for tuple of tuples

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm planning to use PyYAML for a configuration file. Some of the items
in that configuration file are Python tuples of tuples. So, I need a
convenient way to represent them. One can represent Python tuples of
tuples as follows using PyYAML

```
print yaml.load("!!python/tuple [ !!python/tuple [1, 2], !!python/tuple [3, 4]]")
```

However, this is not convenient notation for a long sequence of
items. I think it should be possible to define a custom tag, like
python/tuple_of_tuples. I.e. something like

```
yaml.load("!!python/tuple_of_tuples [[1,2], [3,4]]")
```

See my first attempt to define this below, by mimicking how
python/tuple is defined, and trying to do similar subclassing. It
fails, but gives an idea what I am after, I think. I have a second
attempt that works, but is a cheat, since it just calls `eval`.

If I can't find anything better I'll just use that. However, YAML is
intended as a replacement for ConfigObj, which uses INI files, and is
considerably less powerful than YAML, and I used the same approach
(namely `eval`) for tuples of tuples. So in that respect it will be no
worse.

A proper solution would be most welcome.

I have a couple of comments on my first solution.

1. I'd have thought that the constructor
   `construct_python_tuple_of_tuples` would return the completed
   structure, but in fact it seems to return an empty structure as
   follows

   ```
   ([], [])
   ```

   I traced the calls, and there seems to be a lot of complicated stuff
   happening after `construct_python_tuple_of_tuples` is called.

   The value that  is returned is a tuple of lists  of integers, so quite
   close  to the  desired result.  So,  the structure  must be  completed
   later.

   The line with

   ```
   tuple([tuple(t) for t in x])
   ```

   was my attempt to coerce the list of tuples to a tuple of tuples, but
   if I return that from `construct_python_tuple_of_tuples`, then the
   resulting call to `yaml.load("!!python/tuple_of_tuples [[1,2], [3,4]]")` is just

   ```
   ((),())
   ```
2. Not sure what is with the

   ```
   yaml.org,2002
   ```

   Why 2002?

#### First attempt

```
import yaml
from yaml.constructor import Constructor

def construct_python_tuple_of_tuples(self, node):
     # Complete content of construct_python_tuple
     # is
     # return tuple(self.construct_sequence(node))

     print "node", node
     x = tuple(self.construct_sequence(node))
     print "x", x
     foo = tuple([tuple(t) for t in x])
     print "foo", foo
     return x

Constructor.construct_python_tuple_of_tuples =
construct_python_tuple_of_tuples

Constructor.add_constructor(
         u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple_of_tuples',
         Constructor.construct_python_tuple_of_tuples)

y = yaml.load("!!python/tuple_of_tuples [[1,2], [3,4]]")
print "y", y, type(y)
print y[0], type(y[0])
print y[0][0], type(y[0][0])
```

The results are

```
node SequenceNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple_of_tuples',
value=[SequenceNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq',
value=[ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value=u'1'),
ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value=u'2')]),
SequenceNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq',
value=[ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value=u'3'),
ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value=u'4')])])

x ([], [])

foo ((), ())

y ([1, 2], [3, 4]) <type 'tuple'>

y[0] [1, 2] <type 'list'>

y[0][0] 1 <type 'int'>
```

#### Second attempt

```
import yaml
from yaml import YAMLObject, Loader, Dumper

class TupleOfTuples(YAMLObject):
    yaml_loader = Loader
    yaml_dumper = Dumper

    yaml_tag = u'!TupleOfTuples'
    #yaml_flow_style = ...

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
        import ast
        print "node", node
    print "node.value", node.value, type(node.value)
        return ast.literal_eval(node.value)

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        return node

t = yaml.load("!TupleOfTuples ((1, 2), (3, 4))")
print "t", t, type(t)
```

The results are:

```
node ScalarNode(tag=u'!TupleOfTuples', value=u'((1, 2), (3, 4))')
node.value ((1, 2), (3, 4)) <type 'unicode'>
t ((1, 2), (3, 4)) <type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Just loading lists as usual, then converting the lists to tuples before passing the configuration on to the rest of the code is not acceptable, I suppose?

Comment: @delnan Lists of lists of integers would probably be Ok. Is that something that is easier to do?

Comment: It's trivial, as YAML supports lists and integers natively ;-)

Comment: @delnan So it does. I wonder why it can't handle tuples of tuples as well. Maybe I can manage with lists of lists. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

To start with question 2 first: 2002 was the year this kind of tag was introduced in the Sep 1, 2002 version of the [YAML 1.0 draft](http://yaml.org/spec/history/2002-09-01.html)

Question 1 is more complicated. If you do:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import yaml

lol = [[1,2], [3,4]]  # list of lists
print(yaml.dump(lol))
```

you get (A):

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

But actually this is short for (B):

```
!!seq [
  !!seq [
    !!int "1",
    !!int "2",
  ],
  !!seq [
    !!int "3",
    !!int "4",
  ],
]
```

which is short for (C):

```
!<tag:yaml.org,2002:seq> [
  !<tag:yaml.org,2002:seq> [
    !<tag:yaml.org,2002:int> "1",
    !<tag:yaml.org,2002:int> "2",
  ],
  !<tag:yaml.org,2002:seq> [
    !<tag:yaml.org,2002:int> "3",
    !<tag:yaml.org,2002:int> "4",
  ],
]
```

A, B and C all load to the original list of list, because the seq(uence) is a built in type.

I don't think that extending the syntax of yaml (with e.g. `()` indicating a tuple would be a good idea. To minimize tags you reduce your example to:

```
yaml_in = "!tuple [ !tuple [1, 2], !tuple [3, 4]]"
```

and add a constructor:

```
yaml.add_constructor("!tuple", construct_tuple)
```

but this pushes the problem to creating the `construct_tuple` function. The one for a sequence (in `constructor.py`) is:

```
def construct_yaml_seq(self, node):
    data = []
    yield data
    data.extend(self.construct_sequence(node))
```

But you cannot just replace the `[]` in there with `()` as changing the tuple by extending it will not work (the reason for this two step creation, with a `yield`, is e.g. to allow circular references in complex types like sequence and mapping).

You should define a `Tuple()` class that behaves like a list until "locked" (which you would do at the end of the contruction), and from then on it should behave like a tuple (i.e. no more modification). The following does so without subclassing `yaml.YAMLObject`, so you have to explicitly provide and register the constructor and representer for the Class.

```
class Tuple(list):

    def _lock(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_is_locked'):
            return
        self._is_locked = True
        self.append = self._append
        self.extend = self._extend

    def _append(self, item):
        raise AttributeError("'Tuple' object has no attribute 'append'")

    def _extend(self, items):
        raise AttributeError("'Tuple' object has no attribute 'extend'")

    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + ', '.join((str(e) for e in self)) + ')'

    # new style class cannot assign something to special method
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if getattr(self, '_is_locked', False):
            raise TypeError("'Tuple' object does not support item assignment")
        list.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key, value):
        if getattr(self, '_is_locked', False):
            raise TypeError("'Tuple' object does not support item deletion")
        list.__delitem__(self, key, value)

    @staticmethod
    def _construct_tuple(loader, data):
        result = Tuple()
        yield result
        result.extend(loader.construct_sequence(data))
        result._lock()

    @staticmethod
    def _represent_tuple(dumper, node):
        return dumper.represent_sequence("!tuple", node)

# let yaml know how to handle this
yaml.add_constructor("!tuple", Tuple._construct_tuple)
yaml.add_representer(Tuple, Tuple._represent_tuple)
```

With that in place you can do:

```
yaml_in = "!tuple [ !tuple [1, 2], !tuple [3, 4]]"
#yaml_in = "!tuple [1, 2]"

data = yaml.load(yaml_in)
print(data)
print(data[1][0])
print(type(data))
```

to get:

```
((1, 2), (3, 4))
3
<class '__main__.Tuple'>
```

This is not a real `tuple`, but it doesn't allow `list`-like actions. The following activities all throw the appropriate error:

```
# test appending to the tuple,
try:
    data.append(Tuple([5, 6]))
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    raise NotImplementedError
# test extending the tuple,
try:
    data.extend([5, 6])
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    raise NotImplementedError
# test replacement of an item
try:
    data[0] = Tuple([5, 6])
except TypeError:
    pass
else:
    raise NotImplementedError
# test deletion of an item
try:
    del data[0]
except TypeError:
    pass
else:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

And finally you can do:

```
print(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=True))
```

for the following output:

```
!tuple [!tuple [1, 2], !tuple [3, 4]]
```

---

If you really want `!tuple [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` to create a Tuple of Tuples, you can do so by keeping context state in the the `Baseloader` class of `yaml` and overriding the method that construct python object from the sequences to Tuples or lists depending on context. That would probably have to be a stack of context states, to allow for nested use of !tuple as well as non-nested use, and some explicit overriding to get lists within tuples when using `!!seq` as tag.

---

I might have not checked `Tuple()` for completeness, and only implemented the restrictions that `tuple` has compared to `list` that immediately came to mind.
I tested this with my enhanced version of PyYAML: [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml), but this should work the same in PyYAML itself.